# Detecting the local style in a text with ConTeXt

Tags: context, bold, italic

I would like to detect the local style in a text. What is the ConTeXt equivalent of such these LaTeX commands?

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@shape}{it}}{italic}{not italic}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\f@series}{bf}}{bold}{not bold}
```

I especially need the equivalent of `\f@shape` and `\f@series` commands (I know how to do a string comparison: `\doifelse`).

Comment: Check the value of `\fontalternative`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities come to mind that have different use cases.

## Emphases

Using emphases and
[alternative styles](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Style_Alternatives)
you can just test for `\currenthighlight` which will expand to the
name given in the highlight definition.

```
% macros=mkvi

%% 1. define a couple styles
\setupbodyfont [iwona]

\definecharacterkerning [letterspace:wide] [factor=.125]
\definealternativestyle [emph:1] [{\feature [+] [smallcaps]}]
\definealternativestyle [emph:2] [{\setcharacterkerning [letterspace:wide]}]

%% 2. define emphases that use the styles
\definehighlight [emphone]   [style=emph:1]
\definehighlight [emphtwo]   [style=emph:2]
\definehighlight [emphthree] [emphtwo] [style=emph:2,color=red] %% derived

%% 3. define a conditional
\def \doifcurrenthighlight #name#true#false{%
  \doifelse{\currenthighlight}{#name}{#true}{#false}%
}

\starttext

  Some \emphone {important} text, and something marked up
  \emphtwo {differently}.

  Print current emphasis name: \emphone {\currenthighlight}.

  Print only if matching emphasis:
  \startitemize
          \item \emphone   {\currenthighlight} \emphone   {\doifcurrenthighlight  {emphone}{Yes}{No}}.
          \item \emphtwo   {\currenthighlight} \emphtwo   {\doifcurrenthighlight  {emphone}{Yes}{No}}.
          \item \emphthree {\currenthighlight} \emphthree {\doifcurrenthighlight  {emphtwo}{Yes}{No}}.
          \item \emphthree {\currenthighlight} \emphthree {\doifcurrenthighlight{emphthree}{Yes}{No}}.
  \stopitemize

\stoptext
```

The obvious limitation is -- as demonstrated by the test for
`emphthree` -- that you cannot test for the “super-macro” that the
current one inherits from.

[image: demo image]

## Raw Font Switches

Without a description of what the `\f@shape` and `\f@series` macros
are supposed to accomplish it is hard to tell whether a “literal”
translation of your Latex code is possible.
From the names I’d guess they are NFSS related (please correct me!),
which is highly Latex specific so they are unlikely to have a direct
counterpart in Context.
By default, [Context defines a different set of styles and shapes](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/font-ini.mkvi#L130),
whose properties are exposed via macros:

- `\fontalternative`: the name of the alternative, e. g. `bf`,
  `rm`, etc.
- `\fontsize`: current font size in pt.
- `\fontstyle`: name of the style, e. g. `rm`, `ss`, etc.

These should allow for a good approximation of your Latex example at
the price of using raw formatting directives.
However, above solution utilizing style alternatives is more idiomatic
and should be preferred in hand-written code.

Comment: You are right that `\f@series`, _etc._ are NFSS-related: they are used to track the different 'font axes' by LaTeX. As ConTeXt stick's with a Knuth-like approach for _e.g._ `\rm` I'm not sure they are really translatable.

Comment: @phg Where can I learn about this syntax `\def \doifcurrenthighlight #name#true#false`?

Comment: @Manuel That’s [*MkVI*](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MkVI) syntax. Context has a preprocessor (see [``luat-mac.lua``](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/luat-mac.lua) that is applied if a file begins with the ``%macros=mkvi`` directive or its name has the extension ``.mkvi``.
The syntax is used extensively all over the Context source. There is not really anything to document since it works as you’d expect it to intuitively: named arguments are placeholders for TeX’s numbered ones.

Comment: That should be `% macros=mkvi` (note the space after `%`).

Comment: @Aditya Actually the [heuristic is even looser](http://git.contextgarden.net/context/context/blob/master/tex/context/base/luat-mac.lua#L191), even allowing for something as ridiculous as ``%foobarmacros=mkvi``.